# vb linq comma seperatet

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

i have a little problem with linq in datatable vb. i try to get mixed result from double grouping but don't know how.

the result should be like this

```
Auftrags-Nr. | TrackingNo
1             - 39414718 
2             - 95712583 ,42579525
```

The datatable looks like this:

```
Auftrags-Nr. | | TrackingNo
1.    1      -  39414718 
2.    1      -  39414718
3.    1      -  39414718  
4.    1      -  39414718
5.    1      -  39414718
6.    2      -  95712583 
7.    2      -  95712583 
8.    2      -  95712583 
9.    2      -  42579525
10.   2      -  42579525
```

My Code looks like this

```
Dim trackdict = From rsx In datatbl Select rsx
       Group By bla = rsx.Field(Of String)("Auftrags-Nr.") Into blagroup = Group
               Select New With {Key bla, .trackingNo = ", " & bla("TrackingNo")}
```

Anybody know a solution?

greetings

Comment: It's not quite clear if those dashes are a actual column (without a name) and if, how they end up in the result (if at all). Cloud you please remove all data (line numbers?, bullet points?) that is not part of your real table data?

Comment: you can see more below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
Dim trackdict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = datatbl.AsEnumerable.
    GroupBy(Function(r) r("Auftrags-Nr.").ToString, Function(r) r("TrackingNo")).
    ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) Join(g.Distinct.ToArray, ", "))
```